# Re-initialize JS after jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Helo there,

I'm using jQuery AJAX to change the whole page. My problem is that some of the JSs doesn't work after I change the content (even though I use some code to reload the JS). Check out what I do:

```
$.ajax( {
        type: "GET",
        url: "url",
        cache: false,
        success: function( response ) 
        {
             //replace page contents
             $("body").html($(response ).find("body").html());
             //reload JS
             $(rsp).find("script").each(function() {
                  $.getScript( $(response ).attr('src') ); 
             });
        }
});
```

This works nicely, the page contents are changing as expected and I actually see the `$.getScript` JS loading have some effect, but there are some things that aren't working - for example the bootstrap toggle menu stops working, sometimes rarely on some elements the CSS is not showing correctly and things like that.

So, any ideas how to reload these correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using `holdReady()`? `$.getScript($(response ).attr('src'), function() {
     $.holdReady(false);
});` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/

Comment: Why you replace all the content of the page? Ajax was born to send and retrieve data from a server in background without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.

Comment: @Dagen Sharew - no, unfortunately holdReady doesn't help.

Comment: @Gabriele Ciech I need that, just hard to explain what I do, but there is no workaround actually.

Comment: If the toggle event gets attached twice it will look like nothing is happening however the event are being called twice so it opens / closes Example... https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/tecs4xxt/ try calling $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').off('click.bs.collapse.data-api') to remove all the click events that are assigned from bootstrap before loading the JS from the other page.

Comment: Yes, the toggle thing was actually caused by this. Thanks, but how about the CSS of the newly loaded elements?